# Is there a more generic word for US-centrism?

Tags: single-word-requests

When an article (or any kind of document) is written specifically from the point of view of a citizen of the United States of America, I could complain about a US-centric bias.

Are there other words for that?  More specifically, is there a word that expresses this without reference to the country in question (in this case, the USA)?

I was thinking of "geographically centric", or geocentric; but I think that's more (accurately) used for thinking that the Earth is the centre of the universe.

Comment: In my case, apatheticism / Weaselism / Cluelessism

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Ethnocentrism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethnocentrism) is “The tendency to look at the world primarily from the perspective of one's own culture.”

More politically, [*nationalism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nationalism) is “The support of one nation's interests to the exclusion of others” and [*chauvinism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chauvinism) is “Excessive patriotism, eagerness for national superiority; [jingoism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jingoism),” or “Unwarranted bias, favoritism, or devotion to one's own particular group, cause, or idea.” Both *chauvinism* and *jingoism* have entertaining etymologies. :)

The term *national bias* is occasionally used ([ice skating example](http://www.iceskatingintnl.com/archive/rules/natbias.htm), [medical scholarship example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2224301)).

Comment: I think `ethnocentrism` best describes what I'm looking for, even though it doesn't really contain a reference to geographic bias.

Comment: Jingoism as I understand it is about aggressive foreign policy.  ethnocentrism sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Nationalism reminds me of political nationalism infamously seen in fascist states.  I would avoid it as a general term unless you wish to evoke that kind of emotion in your audience.

Answer (score 2):

Your title and question body ask about different parts of speech. Your title asks about a noun, while your question body asks about adjectives. That confuses the matter, although both can be answered with similar words.

[Nationalism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nationalism)

[Nationalistic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nationalistic)

Now that term indicates *promoting* a certain country. If you simply mean the writing is neutral in tone but only of interest to people from that country, then that's [national](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/national) as in "national news."

Comment: No. Nationalism actively promotes a certain country.  What I mean is that the text is written in a fairly neutral tone, but several assumptions are being made that are only valid for said country.

Comment: That's why I added the second part of my answer. It is correct to say "That article was pretty national" although it is more commonly put as "That article had national bias."

Answer (score 1):

Parochial almost fits, or insular?

edit: sorry if my answer sounded offensive - I thought the poster was asking for a word for "country-centric" and was giving USA-centric as an example. I didn't mean that the US is parochial (although some bits are!)

Comment: "geocentric" means something else http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_model

Comment: [Parochialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parochialism): "Harvard University said that one of the main purposes of the major curriculum overhaul (the first in three decades) was to overcome American "parochialisms", referring in this case to a national point of view rather than one concerned with any particular small community."

Comment: Parochial originally meant your own parish - but I think it can be applied to a rather larger parish.

Comment: To me, "parochial" has a somewhat condescending connotation, as if the person being typed as "parochial" hadn't seen much of the world, and hence didn't know any better.

Answer (score 1):

*Ethnocentrism* is a possible word. *Ethnocentric* as an adjective.

If you want a word related to US-centrism, *Americentrism* is the word you're looking for. It's an actual word.

Answer (score 0):

How about [*provincialism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/provincialism)? According to the Free Dictionary, this means:

> The condition of being provincial; lack of sophistication or perspective. Also called *provinciality*.